# Как объединить значения в которых одинаковые некоторые поля?

Tags: sql, plsql

Например, имеются вот такие данные:

| Национальность | Должность | Количество рабочих |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Русские | Администратор | 10 |
| Русские | Ассистент | 20 |
| Украинцы | Ассистент | 2 |
| Украинцы | Консультант | 5 |

В этих данных отображается, сколько человек и какой национальности работают на какой либо должности.
Но мне нужно, чтобы выводилось это так:

| Национальность | Должность | Количество рабочих |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Русские | Ассистент | 20 |
| Украинцы | Консультант | 5 |

То есть выводились национальности с должностями, на которых работает большинство людей этой национальности. Совсем непонятно, что нужно делать, чтобы выбрать данные таким образом. Если хотя бы пойму, что нужно искать, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, например, так:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       [Национальность],
       FIRST_VALUE([Должность]) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY [Национальность] 
                  ORDER BY [Количество рабочих] DESC) [Должность],
       MAX([Количество рабочих]) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY [Национальность]) [Количество рабочих]
FROM [table]
```

Или можно получить сперва это максимальное в подзапросе/CTE.

Вот только непонятно, что выводить если для одной национальности две должности имеют одинаковое и максимальное количество...